# About Nslookup Results

Tags: dns-lookup

When I try to resolve `113.181.205.189` and `203.148.85.74`, I get `localhost.` and `HM-DC-BS-BIG.` results:

```
nslookup 113.181.205.189

Non-authoritative answer:
189.205.181.113.in-addr.arpa    name = localhost.




nslookup 203.148.85.74

Non-authoritative answer:
74.85.148.203.in-addr.arpa  name = HM-DC-BS-BIG.
```

What is the reason for this unexpected answers and how do those servers produce this kind of results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the results of doing a reverse DNS (RDNS) lookup using the IP PTR records.

You can think of the PTR record as an opposite of the A record. While the A record points a domain name to an IP address, the PTR record resolves the IP address to a domain/hostname. PTR records are used for reverse DNS lookups.

> Reverse DNS lookups for IPv4 addresses use a reverse IN-ADDR entry in
>   the special domain in-addr.arpa. In this domain, an IPv4 address is
>   represented as a concatenated sequence of four decimal numbers,
>   separated by dots, to which is appended the second level domain suffix
>   .in-addr.arpa. The four decimal numbers are obtained by splitting the
>   32-bit IPv4 address into four 8-bit portions and converting each 8-bit
>   portion into a decimal number. These decimal numbers are then
>   concatenated in the order: least significant 8-bit portion first
>   (leftmost), most significant 8-bit portion last (rightmost). It is
>   important to note that this is the reverse order to the usual
>   dotted-decimal convention for writing IPv4 addresses in textual form.

[RDNS in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)

Comment: Thanks but should not they look like a domain? Say `nslookup 86.220.66.228` resolves to `ACaen-653-1-95-228.w86-220.abo.wanadoo.fr.` I want to ask why those above 2 IPs do not return like proper server domains.

Comment: You are able to set the RDNS records to anything. While they are suppose to be set to a corresponding domain name there is nothing stopping someone from setting them to something else.

Comment: Regarding the 'in-addr.arpa' I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Analog. Another question if you do not mind please. Does `NXDOMAIN` result of `nslookup` mean the related IP is a normal user computer rather than a server? I want to block bot servers so trying to separate servers from normal users by checking a RDNS record is available or not. Do you think `NXDOMAIN` can be used to label normal users?

Comment: @NecNecco No, NXDOMAIN will show if there is no RDNS record set. Many hosts neglect to set RDNS records on all of their addresses which would result in their IPs all displaying NSDOMAIN.

Comment: For example OVH doesn't set the RDNS for all client extra IP space which is a perfect example that even big hosts would output NXDOMAIN on a lot of their IP space.

Comment: Thank you very much @Analog. Much appreciated the details. One another question please. `nslookup 84.59.134.234` returns `dslb-084-059-134-234.084.059.pools.vodafone-ip.de.` Is this a server or normal mobile user phone? It seems to be server but because of vodafone I thought it might be normal user.

Comment: @NecNecco There is no way to know for sure, the best you could do is take an educated guess. Could be a mobile user, could be a server. It does ping back which makes me think it's a server but there is no sure fire way to determine if an IP is a regular user or server aside from looking at the netblock owner and making a guess based on the info you find.

Answer (score 2):

Use `whois ipaddress` instead.

### 113.181.205.189

```
% Information related to '113.181.0.0 - 113.181.255.255'

inetnum:        113.181.0.0 - 113.181.255.255
netname:        VNPT-VNNIC-VN
descr:          VietNam Post and Telecom Corporation
descr:          FTTH Service
country:        VN
admin-c:        NXC1-AP
tech-c:         KNH1-AP
status:         ALLOCATED NON-PORTABLE
mnt-by:         MAINT-VN-VNPT
mnt-irt:        IRT-VNNIC-AP
changed:        hm-changed@vnnic.net.vn 20141128
source:         APNIC

irt:            IRT-VNNIC-AP
address:        Ha Noi, VietNam
phone:          +84-4-35564944
fax-no:         +84-4-37821462
e-mail:         hm-changed@vnnic.net.vn
abuse-mailbox:  hm-changed@vnnic.net.vn
admin-c:        PT174-AP
tech-c:         NTTT1-AP
auth:           # Filtered
mnt-by:         MAINT-VN-VNNIC
changed:        hm-changed@vnnic.net.vn 20101108
source:         APNIC

person:         Khanh Nguyen Hien
nic-hdl:        KNH1-AP
e-mail:         hathm@vdc.com.vn
address:        Vietnam Datacommunications Company (VDC)
address:        Lo IIA Lang Quoc te Thang Long, Cau Giay, Ha Noi
phone:          +84-4-3793 0563
fax-no:         +84-4-32811506
country:        VN
changed:        hm-changed@vnnic.net.vn 20090227
mnt-by:         VNPT
source:         APNIC

person:         Nguyen Xuan Cuong
nic-hdl:        NXC1-AP
e-mail:         cuongnx@vnpt.com.vn
address:        Vietnam Posts and Telecommunications (VNPT)
address:        57 Huynh Thuc Khang
address:        Hanoi, Vietnam
phone:          +84-4-37741236
fax-no:         +84-4-37741205
country:        VN
changed:        hm-changed@vnnic.net.vn 20090922
mnt-by:         MAINT-VN-VNPT
source:         APNIC
```

### 203.148.85.74

```
% Information related to '203.148.84.0 - 203.148.85.255'

inetnum:        203.148.84.0 - 203.148.85.255
netname:        INDOTRANS-ID
descr:          PT. Indotrans Data
descr:          Internet Service Provider
descr:          Gedung Annex lantai dasar, Komplek YTKI
descr:          Jln. Jend. Gatot Subroto No. 44
descr:          Jakarta 12710
country:        ID
admin-c:        DC1015-AP
tech-c:         DC1015-AP
remarks:        Send Spam&  Abuse report to: noc@indotrans.net.id
status:         ALLOCATED PORTABLE
mnt-by:         MNT-APJII-ID
mnt-routes:     MAINT-ID-INDOTRANS
mnt-irt:        IRT-INDOTRANS-ID
changed:        hostmaster@idnic.net 20130502
changed:        hostmaster@idnic.net 20130906
mnt-lower:      MAINT-ID-INDOTRANS
source:         APNIC

irt:            IRT-INDOTRANS-ID
address:        PT. Indotrans Data
address:        Gedung Raudha Lt. 2 Blok B.3
address:        Jl. Terusan Kuningan H.R Rasuna Said No. 21
address:        Jakarta, 12710
e-mail:         noc@indotransdata.net
abuse-mailbox:  noc@indotransdata.net
admin-c:        DC1015-AP
tech-c:         DC1015-AP
auth:           # Filtered
mnt-by:         MAINT-ID-INDOTRANS
changed:        noc@indotransdata.net 20110329
changed:        hostmaster@idnic.net 20110329
source:         APNIC

person:         Dwi Cahyoko
nic-hdl:        DC1015-AP
e-mail:         dwi@indotrans.net.id
address:        Perumahan Bumi Sentosa blok A6 No: 18
address:        RT 08 RW 09, Bogor
phone:          +62-21-68007806
fax-no:         +62-21-5279906
country:        ID
changed:        hostmaster@idnic.net 20080923
changed:        hostmaster@idnic.net 20130906
mnt-by:         MAINT-ID-INDOTRANS
source:         APNIC

% Information related to '203.148.84.0/23AS45289'

route:          203.148.84.0/23
descr:          Route Object of PT Indotrans Data
descr:          Internet Service Provider
descr:          Gedung Annex Lt.Dasar
descr:          Jl. Jendral Gatot Subroto No.44
descr:          Jakarta 12710
country:        ID
origin:         AS45289
mnt-by:         MAINT-ID-INDOTRANS
changed:        hostmaster@idnic.net 20140430
source:         APNIC
```

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc. I just want to learn how do they return those weird results for the nslookup. I do not have whois installed on my CentOS VPS but will try to install it.

Comment: @NecNecco I have no idea. I know that some say that nslookup and whois are the same, but that is not true. Sometimes one is better than the other.

Comment: I would say viewing the actual ASN information for a giving IP address is best.

Comment: @Analog Yeah. I get that another way programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

In DNS, domain registrants and their registrars have authority over A records that resolve domain names to IP addresses. If you register a domain, you get to pick the IP address it resolves to.

On the other hand, IP address blocks are assigned to ISPs that connect machines to the Internet. The PTR records are in special "in-addr.arpa." DNS zones corresponding to the IP address blocks assigned to ISPs. Thus, the ISPs have authority over the rDNS zones. And so, to add those PTR records, you usually need to consult with an ISP, or have the ability to do dynamic DNS updates on the zones. The latter would usually be because the ISP has an insecure DNS server infrastructure.

When an ISP assigns a device an IP address, they usually also add a corresponding PTR record with some geographic information in the data. This allows them to correlate things in their logs easier.

Having rDNS set up also makes flaky software work much faster, when said software tries to log the hostname of a machine when it otherwise would not have one. Without the entry, the software usually times out on DNS after a few seconds, and that feels like the Internet is slow.